# Why Jenkins resets build number in Pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am using Jenkins with multiple tools (node, maven etc) and some of build versions are basing on build number. Jobs configured with Pipeline (Bitbucket Team Project).
Sometimes Jenkins just removes most of builds from branches, and restarts building (like first-time Branch Indexing happens).

Some logs:

```
Sep 7 07:50:07 jenkins-1 nice[21775]: INFO: Skipping job "blablabla" with type org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject
Sep 7 07:50:44 jenkins-1 nice[21775]: WARNING: Failed to load Owner[blablabla/blablabla/initial/13:blablabla/blablabla/initial #13]. Unregistering
Sep 7 07:50:44 jenkins-1 nice[21775]: java.io.IOException: blablabla/blablabla/initial #13 did not yet start
```

Jenkins version: 2.73.2
Any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: This is not actual anymore. The root cause was wrong proxy configuration, which cut headers, which came from bitbucket to notify about new commits.